# Finding commonly occurring words across multiple lists

Tags: python-3.x

I have 5 lists of words. I need to find all words occurring in more than 2 lists. Any word can occur multiple times in a list.

I have used collections.Counter but it only returns the frequencies of all the words in individual lists.

```
a = ['wood', 'tree', 'bark', 'log']

b = ['branch', 'mill', 'boat', 'boat', 'house']

c = ['log', 'tree', 'water', 'boat']

d = ['water', 'log', 'branch', 'water']

e = ['branch', 'rock', 'log']
```

For example, the output from these lists should be ['log':4, 'branch':3] as 'log' is present in 4 lists and 'branch' in 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) the counters - starting with an empty `Counter()`:

```
from collections import Counter

lists = [a, b, c, d, e]
total = sum((Counter(set(lst)) for lst in lists), Counter())
# Counter({'log': 4, 'branch': 3, 'tree': 2, 'boat': 2, 'water': 2,
#          'wood': 1, 'bark': 1, 'house': 1, 'mill': 1, 'rock': 1})
res = {word: occ for word, occ in total.items() if occ > 2}
# {'log': 4, 'branch': 3}
```

note that i convert all the lists to a `set` first in order to avoid double-counts for the words that are more than once in the same list.

---

if you need to know what list the words were from you could try this:

```
lists = {"a": a, "b": b, "c": c, "d": d, "e": e}

total = sum((Counter(set(lst)) for lst in lists.values()), Counter())
# Counter({'log': 4, 'branch': 3, 'tree': 2, 'boat': 2, 'water': 2,
#          'wood': 1, 'bark': 1, 'house': 1, 'mill': 1, 'rock': 1})
res = {word: occ for word, occ in total.items() if occ > 2}
# {'log': 4, 'branch': 3}

word_appears_in = {
    word: [key for key, value in lists.items() if word in value] for word in res
}
# {'log': ['a', 'c', 'd', 'e'], 'branch': ['b', 'd', 'e']}
```

Comment: This does not give the expected output, since the words could be multiple times in the same list

Comment: Thanks! What if I want to know the names of the lists words in res appeared in?

Answer (score 3):

Without `Counter`:

```
a = ['wood', 'tree', 'bark', 'log']
b = ['branch', 'mill', 'boat', 'boat', 'house']
c = ['log', 'tree', 'water', 'boat']
d = ['water', 'log', 'branch', 'water']
e = ['branch', 'rock', 'log']

all_lists = [a, b, c, d, e]
all_words = set().union(w for l in all_lists for w in l)

out = {}
for word in all_words:
    s = sum(word in l for l in all_lists)
    if s > 2:
        out[word] = s

print(out)
```

Prints:

```
{'branch': 3, 'log': 4}
```

---

Edit (to print the names of lists):

```
a = ['wood', 'tree', 'bark', 'log']
b = ['branch', 'mill', 'boat', 'boat', 'house']
c = ['log', 'tree', 'water', 'boat']
d = ['water', 'log', 'branch', 'water']
e = ['branch', 'rock', 'log']

all_lists = {'a':a, 'b':b, 'c':c, 'd':d, 'e':e}
all_words = set().union(w for l in all_lists.values() for w in l)

out = {}
for word in all_words:
    s = sum(word in l for l in all_lists.values())
    if s > 2:
        out[word] = s

for k, v in out.items():
    print('Word : {}'.format(k))
    print('Count: {}'.format(v))
    print('Lists: {}'.format(', '.join(kk for kk, vv in all_lists.items() if k in vv )))
    print()
```

Prints:

```
Word : log
Count: 4
Lists: a, c, d, e

Word : branch
Count: 3
Lists: b, d, e
```

Comment: @cliff Edited my answer and added version where it prints the names of lists where the word is in